# Web services vs Spring remoting

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-ws

I quite didnt get the difference between a regular web service implemented either through spring or axis versus Remoting.

If my question is not at all related, I am just confused between spring web services vs spring remoting. When to go for remoting and when to go with a web service.

Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/) is a dedicated Spring Project (using Spring's own Web Service technology), whereas [Spring Remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) is a common approach of integrating different third party remoting technologies.

Spring-WS is always contract-first, while Spring Remoting is often code-first.

Answer (score 5):

Your choice of using Spring remoting or web services depends on whether you want to use SOAP or not.

All Spring services should start life as interface-based POJO services, of course.  That way you can worry only about implementation and interface; remote access can be an afterthought that way.

Once your Spring POJO service is tested and running, you can choose between a myriad of remoting choices: EJB (RMI-based; Java-only clients), HTTP (any client that can create an HTTP client), web services (SOAP and WSDL), etc.  Your choice depends on the types of clients you anticipate and the wire protocol you'd like to use.

Comment: I only understood that remoting is an afterthought once you completed the implementation of webservice and what type of clients am I going to expect. I need little bit more theory, can you guide me to an appropriate place where I can get more detail about the differences and when to go for remoting and when to be a regular webservice. Lastly I appreciate your quick response